# Why won't my console app work with 25 arguments or more?

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am making a console application where I drop files onto the .exe from Explorer and it will move them to the appropriate folder based on rules I have set in the logic of the program.

The program works great, but when I select more than 25 files and drop them on my .exe I get an error:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

If I only drop 24 files from the same set it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: > On computers running Microsoft Windows
> XP or later, the maximum length of the
> string that you can use at the command
> prompt is 8191 characters. On
> computers running Microsoft Windows
> 2000 or Windows NT 4.0, the maximum
> length of the string that you can use
> at the command prompt is 2047
> characters. I tested it out and yep thats what im running into. can anyone think of a way around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on your platform, you may be running into the maximum command line length.  See [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) for more info.

"On computers running Microsoft Windows XP or later, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 8191 characters. On computers running Microsoft Windows 2000 or Windows NT 4.0, the maximum length of the string that you can use at the command prompt is 2047 characters."

Comment: you beat me to it.

now i guess the question is how can i get around it?

Comment: This seems right to me.  The reason you'd get a "Cannot find specified path etc" error is that it's trying to hunt down a partial file name.  

I see you tagged this C#.  Try setting a breakpoint on the loop that tests files, conditionally to only trigger on the 24th or 25th iteration (or only on 25.txt, which is the 25th file you put in).  Then look and see if you are getting a partial file name.

Comment: Double posting it seems.  How to get around?  Easy, piping.  I'm not sure exactly how in CMD to do it, but you can do something like this in Powershell or *nix shells:
dir | MyProgram 

That will list the contents of a directory, and then feed each item one at a time into MyProgram (which is, of course, your app).

Comment: I made a new updated question to ask what i really wnated

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916794/what-is-the-sleakest-way-to-proccess-multiple-files

Answer (score 2):

Is the number of files causing the maximum length of the command line (and thus arguments) to be exceeded, which causes this error?

Comment: could be

thats what im asking i guess

Comment: @Rob - Your answer should have been a comment and not posted as answer. -1

Comment: @divo - my reasoning: for a Newb that would have been acceptable, but for a veteran of the site to post a question that restates what the OP is already saying is not helpful.

Comment: +1, so the answer was phrased as a question, however "causing the maximum length of the command line (and thus arguments) to be exceeded" was correct

Comment: @Ichiban - err, no. I'll phrase my answers in any way I please. Giving a -1 because you don't like the way an answer is phrased is a little bit counterproductive to the aims of the site don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the follow-up, a little more info about the purpose of the app might be required, but if possible you might change your command line args to accept a folder path and a pattern to match all the necessary files you want to route. Or change it to a GUI app with a grid that you can drag-drop into.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. the eloquent part (or at least i thought it was) of my program is that it doesn't need to run in the background it would start up with the arguments given then die when it was done. If i created a winform that i could simply drag files on to the winform i could get around it but it adds a step to a proccess -- the other idea was to have a folder with a systemfilewatcher but that would have to run in the background